# ValueError: Unsupported value "0.5" for operation when setting pos in TextStim

Tags: psychopy

I'm making a task in the builder view of PyschoPy, I want the position of the text to change depending on the trial. I've got the Y position of the text (TextPosY) in an excel sheet with the positions but I keep getting the error above. If I manually enter (0, 0.5) into the "Position [x ,y]" box then 0, 0.5 works but when it gets 0.5 from (0, $TextPosY) then it suddenly says 0.5 is an unsupported value.

I've got the settings set to norm, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us the full error message and what the contents are of your conditions file. But going from the title of your post, which has `"0.5"` in quotes, it looks like PsychoPy is interpreting that column as text, rather than as numeric. Look for what non-numeric characters may be in that column to cause it to think that.

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes I thought that too. The only non-numeric cell is the title, I've formatted the column in excel to be numeric. The full error message is as follows: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 312, in <module>
    text.setPos(TextPosX, TextPosY, log=False)
  File "path", line 1360, in setPos
    setAttribute(self, 'pos', val2array(newPos, False), log, operation)
  File "path", line 122, in setAttribute
    raise ValueError(msg % vals)
ValueError: Unsupported value "0.5" for operation when setting pos in TextStim
##### Experiment ended. #####